# Paypal request money - does it have API?

Tags: email, paypal

There is a [request money by email](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/req/index-outside) feature on paypal - (where you can put email of some person and he can send you money)

Does it have an API ? (So I want to request money by email from my application)

Comment: I hope not, or we'll watch a new spam kind to born.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the answer is - no such API

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you can send invoices (request money) by email with the [Invoicing Service API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_IntroInvoiceAPI)

Comment: I think this link is 404d

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own personal `PayPal.Me/name` link (it's open to both personal and business use) and it will be associated with your PayPal account.

Whenever you need to collect money from anyone, just send them your [PayPal.Me](https://www.paypal.me/) link via email (or chat, SMS...).

Your payer clicks the link, enters the amount, and that's it. The money is in your PayPal account in seconds (you'll pay the standard PayPal fee for a business account).

To request a specific amount just add it to the end of your link. For example, use

```
PayPal.Me/name/25
```

to request 25 USD. You can request a specific currency by adding the currency code to the amount, e.g.

```
PayPal.Me/name/25EUR
```

Answer (score 2):

IT has that facility. you have to generate url. its mentioned at

https://www.x.com/developers/community/blogs/ppmtschad/creating-hyperlink-instead-paypal-button

Answer (score 1):

First method is to use the Invoice API to generate the request and have paypal send out the email.
See https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/Merchant/bizui/IntegrationDirect-outside

Second method is to use the buy now buttons. First create the product in the paypal account, then create a buy now button for it. It'll give an option for Email. You can then send that link out whenever you want. 
See https://www.x.com/developers/community/blogs/ppmtschad/creating-hyperlink-instead-paypal-button and

Third option is the rarely advertised custom cart URL. I don't have anything that details this however the following sample link can get you started.
https://secure.paypal.com/xclick/business=EMAIL%40DOMAIN.COM&item_name=Cart_Invoice_Custom_Name&amount=123.45&return=www.yourwebsite.com&currency_code=EUR
Remember to properly URL encode things. All the variables for dynamic buttons that I've tried work fine. Details of those are at https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_techview_outside